# How to use switch case with string resources

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, switch-statement

How can I use the switch case scenario with string resources rather than hard coded names? My strings are exactly the same names used for the spellings of them.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            MainListAdapter adapter = (MainListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            Main continent = adapter.getItem(position);
               if (mTwoPane) {
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(continent, rowView);

                    Fragment newFragment;
                    switch (stringRes) {
                        case R.id.africa:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                            break;
                        case R.id.asia:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                            break;
                        case R.id.europe:
                            newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                            break;
                        default:
                            newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                    }

                    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
              }
```

Comment: Note that this sort of switch is best replaced by reflection and/or a factory.

Answer (score 4):

Switch labels (that’s the `"africa"` in `case "africa":`) must be [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) according to [JLS § 14.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12). So if you want to use `switch`, you’ll have to store the string resource value in a constant variable and then use that constant as the switch label.

Example (use *either* class constants or local constants):

```
class Example {
  public static final String CONTINENT_EUROPE =
      getResources().getString(R.string.europe);  // Option 1: class constants
  public static final String CONTINENT_NORTHERN_AMERICA =
      getResources().getString(R.string.northernAmerica);

  public void foo() {
    final String continentAfrica =
        getResources().getString(R.string.africa);  // Option 2: local constants
    final String continentAsia =
        getResources().getString(R.string.asia);
    switch (continent) {
    // Option 1:
    case continentAfrica:
      newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
      break;
    case continentAsia:
      newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
      break;
    // Option 2:
    case CONTINENT_EUROPE:
      newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
      break;
    case CONTINENT_NORTHERN_AMERICA:
      newFragment = new FragmentNorthernAmerica();
      break;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this could work.. use integers.

```
public void switchFragments(int stringRes){
    if (mTwoPane) {
                View rowView = view;
                setItemSelected(continent, rowView);

                Fragment newFragment;
                switch (stringRes) {
                    case R.id.africa:
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                        break;
                    case R.id.asia:
                        newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                        break;
                    case R.id.europe:
                        newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                        break;
                    default:
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                }

                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) view.getContext();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
}
```

Now all you have to do is call it like this

```
switchFragments(R.id.africa);
```

This will go to the case labeled R.id.africa and switch the fragment.
It will also work with different languages, because its just an ID of a resource.

Comment: @hitch.united After using your suggestion I get this error: `Variable 'id' is already defined in this scope`.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this scenario the simplest way is you can just use "simple if else statement" to avoid declaring extra static variables. And also to add support on locale changes.

```
private String[] titles;

void initialize(){
    titles = new String[]{getString(R.string.europe),getString(R.string.africa)};
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    String title = titles[position];

    if (title.equals(getString(R.string.europe))) {
        return new EuropeFragment();
    } else if (title.equals(getString(R.string.africa))) {
        return new AfricaFragment();
    } else {
        return new DefaultFragment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare them as constants like this:

```
public static final String COUNTRY_AFRICA = "africa";
public static final String COUNTRY_ASIA = "asia";

switch (country.toLowerCase()) {
    case COUNTRY_AFRICA:
         newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
         break;
    // etc..
```

This is better than hardcoding because you will be able to reuse these constants across the app.

If those are UI strings you can declare them in `strings.xml`

Comment: Bear in mind that my app will be in different languages. You've hardcoded "africa" and "asia". Can't I use `getResources().getString(R.string.africa)` and `getResources().getString(R.string.asia)` instead ?

Comment: I havn't tested this but maybe you could use the string resource id? then you can use the switch with integers.

Comment: Is "africa" a UI string? I mean, is it displayed to the user? If yes, then the logic is wrong. You shouldn't build conditions depending on the strings that change with locale

Comment: So, do not use `getResources().getString()` in a switch-case then. Go ahead with the solution that @ChrisKo proposed. Or mine solution :) They both do the same thing actually.

Answer (score -2):

You should declare it as an enum:

```
public enum Continent{
    africa, asia, europe
}

public Fragment getFragment(String continentKey){
    Continent continent = Continent.valueOf(continentKey);
    return getFragment(continent);
}

public Fragment getFragment(Continent aContinent){
    Fragment newFragment;
    switch(aContinent){
        case asia:
            newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
            break;
        case europe:
            newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
            break;
        case africa: default:
            newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
            break;
    }
    return newFragment;
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that my app will be in different languages. E.g. the French don't say "Africa", they say "Afrique" Can't I use `getResources().getString(R.string.africa)` and `getResources().getString(R.string.asia)` instead?

Comment: you need to use the resource-key (e.g."africa") for that. using the resource-value (e.g. "Afrique") makes no sense.

Comment: Please edit your answer as necessary, I want to use string resources that are specified in the strings.xml file